# Jenkins not starting a new build on branch creation/deletion

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

**The idea:**
On every push to a git repo, new Jenkins task build should be started. If the change is:

- new branch created - Jenkins will get the source, do some setup and run a Docker container, where this branch can be tested, etc.
- new push - Jenkins should rebuild the source
- branch deleted - Jenkins should delete the files that have been build, delete DBs, shut down containers, etc.

**The setup:**

- BitBucket repo with webhook pointing to the Jenkins URL
- Jenkins running on a local server with the BitBucket plugin and the task is to "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket"

**The problem:**

When a branch is created/deleted the BitBucket webhook fires, and Jenkins is processing the request (So far, so good).

In the Jenkins logs I see:
"Received commit hook notification for..." BUT the "BitBucket Hook Log" screen shows the following:

```
    Polling SCM changes on master
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 
.....
.....
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repositories
 > git config remote.origin.url ...
Fetching upstream changes from ...
 > git --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > git config --local credential.username ....
 > git config --local credential.helper store --
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ... +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
Polling for changes in
Seen branch in repository ....
Done. Took 6.6 sec
No changes
```

So it's basically saying there are no changes, and the job is not running.
If I made a code change and push that change to BitBucket, the job starts as expected and is running fine.

Any ideas how to force Jenkins to start a new build on branch creation/deletion?

Comment: I have the same problem with Github, whenever a new branch is created, webhook get's the [create] request, but Jenkins doesn't trigger the build. Github logs shows at last 'No changes'. But, If I do push on the newly created branch, then Jenkins does the build. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: From git this makes sense - creating a branch only creates a new meta information, but the last commit is the same. You need to handle the branch name for branch creation separately.

Answer (score 0):

I've released a new version to bitbucket-plugin (v1.1.30) that allows building upon receiving a new branch was created event